# 2500 reputation is a high requirement for just suggest tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, reputation, tags

Suggesting tag synonyms requires 2500 reputation which seems REALLY steep for something so basic. It's strange because there is a badge for 3 such suggestions yet it's only considered a *bronze* badge.

Comment: I've seen... An utterly *ridiculous* amount of drama surrounding certain tag synonyms. Yes, it's basic - but that doesn't mean "uncontroversial"!

Answer (score 4):

2500 may seem high now, but 2 or 3 years from now, I assure you -- it won't.

The limit is there to ensure that truly *experienced* users are coordinating on the tags, which are the primary organizational system on the site.

It's OK if only a few users and the moderators are making these decisions now; as the site grows, more people will gain the privilege and can contribute to the process.

Comment: 2 or 3 years to make AirPort a synonym to Wi-Fi... That's a bit steep...

Comment: It's not that nobody can create synonyms today. This is also the reason why ♦s (Community Mods) exist.